# How to redirect to a specific page for push notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, swift4

I am working on ios push notification and need to redirect it to a specific page on tapping it.
How can this functionality be achieved ?

Comment: You can conform to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate Protocol and implement didReceive method, this will be called when the notification clicked.

Comment: Can u please give an example for its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


        print("userInfo:->  \(userInfo)")
        let redirect_flag = userInfo["redirect_flag"]as! String


        if application.applicationState == .inactive {

            //MARK: - code here to redirect when app is not in background or inactive


            if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: KEY_IS_LOGIN) != nil)
            {

                switch redirect_flag {
                case "1":

                    print("redirect controller")

                case "2":

                      print("redirect controller")

                case "3":

                      print("redirect controller")

                default:
                    break
                }

            }



        }else {

             //MARK: - code here to redirect when app is in background or active mode

            switch redirect_flag {
            case "1":

                print("redirect controller")

            case "2":

                print("redirect controller")

            case "3":

                print("redirect controller")

            default:
                break
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a specific page when a notification received ,you must first handle received push notification,

To handle recieved push notification follow the steps below:

1. In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` set messaging delegate to self
2. Register for remote notification. This shows a permission dialog on first run
3. You need to handle notification registration for iOS 10 and before
4. implement `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to start receiving messaging , here you can handle received data, parse it and redirect ... this will be called when notification tapped for devices that run iOS lower than 10
5. For iOS 10 and later you can conform to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`, and implement `didReceive` method.That's it

**Example:**

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        // [START set_messaging_delegate]
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        // [END set_messaging_delegate]

        // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
        // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
```

Handling Recived messaged :

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

Handle Received notifications for iOS 10 and later:

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    //When clicked
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        //You can here parse it, and redirect.
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```